# VBA - How to insert a star in the cell with the highest value?

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to insert a small star icon (or a star image) in the cell that has the highest value compared to other cells. For example I would like to have a star in cell A2, replacing the number of the highest value. So, instead of 19, there should be a star. Is there any way to achieve this using vba or conditional formatting?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Given that you mentioned conditional formatting, it is possible to do this without VBA. Given the range in your image, you can set up a conditional formatting rule that applies to this range:

[image: conditional formatting rule]

- The rule should apply to your range (A2:F2).
- You should use the **Format only cells that contain** rule.
- You should select **Cell value equal to** `=MAX($A$2:$F$2)`
- When specifying the formatting that should be applied, select custom number formatting, and use `\*` (the backslash for a literal asterisk).

You get a couple of benefits from using this approach:

1. You keep the original value.
2. You don't need VBA, so can continue saving this as a regular workbook.
3. Related to No. 1: It's easier to change the rule (e.g. to use a character other than asterisk, or to make the asterisk stand out more, or display the number *with* an asterisk).

Comment: i really appriciate the answer. But as i mentioned, i would like to insert a star image or icon or even doodle in the cell and not an asterisk symbol. Is there any solution for this?

Comment: @anis: To my knowledge, conditional formatting does not allow an image to be placed in the cell. Although I would question the benefit of using an image over an asterisk, which you can style to your heart's content (change the color, font, etc.) If you absolutely need an image instead of a literal asterisk, you could probably rework one of the other users' solutions to add an image. But the code is going to be more complex, having to deal with `Shape` objects probably.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to replace the value (removing the value and changing it to *) you can find the maximum value if your range, then for each cell having this maximum value, change the value to *.

For example :

```
Dim myRange As Range
Dim maxvalue As Double

'Set your range to whatever it needs to be
Set myRange = *whatever*

'Find the maximum value in your range
maxvalue = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(myRange)

For Each mCell In myRange.Cells
    If mCell.Value = maxvalue Then
        mCell.Value = "*"
    End If
Next mCell
```

Comment: i really appriciate the answer. But as i mentioned, i would like to insert a star image or icon or even doodle in the cell and not an asterisk symbol. Is there any solution for this? Because i have tried this code, and add an image into the cell but it doesnt work as i wanted.

Comment: You can display an image on a cell, otherwise I'm gonna guess that you can't

Comment: I tried using `mCell.Value = ActiveSheet.Pictures.Insert("Q:\...\star.png")` but the placement of the picture is not in the cell. It just appears anywhere in the worksheet.

Comment: You have to tell the position to excel, you'll find an example [here](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/excel/vba-help-for-a-macro-inserting-picture-from-file/m-p/189094).

Comment: but can you please show me how to apply the above example in your code? I am really new to VBA so I am not very familiar with this.

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
Option Explicit

Sub LoopingThroughTable()

    Dim tbl As ListObject
    Dim i As Long, MaxValue As Double
    Dim FoundCell As Range
    
    'Set the table
    Set tbl = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").ListObjects("Table1")

    'Loop Through Every Row in Table
    With tbl
    
        For i = 1 To .DataBodyRange.Rows.Count
        
            'Get the max value
            MaxValue = WorksheetFunction.Max(.ListRows(i).Range)
            'Find in which column max value appears
            Set FoundCell = .DataBodyRange.Rows(i).Find(MaxValue, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)
            'Change the value
            .DataBodyRange(i, FoundCell.Column).Value = "*"
            
        Next i
        
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: i really appriciate the answer. But as i mentioned, i would like to insert a star image or icon or even doodle in the cell and not an asterisk symbol. Is there any solution for this?